# How to find all files with size greater than...?

Tags: software-recommendation, disk-usage

Is there any GUI software that can explore a tree and find all files with size greater than some amount? Neither Nautilus nor Nemo seem to be able to do this. In my memory, I could do this with PC-Tools in DOS 3.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gnome-search-tool` is what I use.  Very simple.  It has the "Size is at least" filter where you can specify minimum file size.  See screen print for searching my ISOs folder with a minimum size of 10,000,000 KB in size.

[image: gnome-search-tool minimum file size]

Comment: Thank you rik.shaw, I completly forgot this since I use unity, and as I thought gnome-search-tool was a feature/companion of Nautilus (what I now know is false) growing ...more and more spartan, so I switched to Nemo (which, btw, doesn't help more in that matter of searching), so I was stuck.

I will give a try back to it although I remember issues in gnome-search-tool keeping searching for hours when it met unauthorized directories or files or looping through links.

Anyway, even if there isn't a better tool, at least it was the kind of answer I expected.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 46):

- In the shell tools we have `find`:

  ```
  find / -size +1M
  ```

  For files over 1 megabyte.
- And in the GUI's we have the Disk Usage Analitizer (baobab):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install baobab
  baobad
  ```

There is a bunch more on this [question of SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/9847/235569), but for all ends and propose baobad is enough.

Comment: Thank you Braiam, but baobab can't be useful as it won't have file search/sort option. More, since Unity the menu is broken (no more edit/preferences to exclude files/folder) and I get an error analysing my own "/home/me or some of its subfolders", maybe authorizations of .ssh, and no message to direct me to a log... so.

find may work better, but it is not a gui, and everytime (which is not often) it could be useful, in the urgency, I forgot the syntax, so... find is not for my humanity.

Comment: @useful there are a bunch more on the SU link, I won't bother to bring them since... mm... it will give the impression that you want a list and you want not (nor is encouraged in SE), either way, give the link a shot, if you feel that some of them solves your problem. BTW, as you can notice I prefer CLI solutions over GUI's since... mmm... I'm like that ;).

Answer (score 21):

When I need make more free space on servers I use this command. It find all files bigger then 50 MB and "du -h" make berret list of files and "sort -n" after pipe make list numericcaly sorted by file size.

```
find / -type f -size +50M -exec du -h {} \; | sort -n
```

Comment: Oh what a nice a handy GUI. It is just too easy for a newb like me, but waiting for the same in assembly language... waiting for the machine code which is the top in elegance, I'll stick to gnome-search-tool.  -1

Comment: I know you search GUI tool, but if you will learn more with Bash then you know this in all distros and environments. For easier understanding I explain this for you.

If you need I can explain this in more details, it is really easy and very useful.

Comment: Thank you zorbon.cz. Sorry for my ironic way, but I have so much other issue with command line tool that should work just as intended but doesn't, so then I easy get irascible when some answer comes that obviously doesn't take care of the care I asked with. Well the point is that I'm not that newb, intermediate computers user instead, so I often run in frustration with Linux... yes I know it's the price of freedom and there is still Windows if I want to switch back... but I put the finger in the shredder. Anyway I recognize your gentle pre-comment on your command line: I didn't see it at first

Comment: My main frustration is how could I dare advise anyone to use this OS when I can't even help myself so often.

Comment: Sorry, maybe one of my reason to answer that is fact that I now use Windows 8.1 :-) since Windows 8 RTM (more than 2 years) and I can not switch back to linux (and I'd like do it), because there are not alternatives to some tools) and now I donť know "nothing" about GUI. But I see CLI every day as sysadmin (I manages higher tens of servers running on CentOS or some on Debian). I understand your last mention and it is true fact.

Answer (score 7):

And if you are looking to search for a particular type of file, use this:

```
find . -name *.js -size +1M -ls
```

Searches for all files of type .js with a size greater than 1MB